# Characterization(?) of product measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

What I want to prove is,

If $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{N},\nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and $\psi$ is a measure on $\mathfrak{M}\otimes\mathfrak{N}$, such that
$$ \psi(A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B) $$
for all measurable rectangles $A\times B$. Then, $\psi=\mu\otimes\nu$.

I want to show that $\mathcal C=\{E\in\mathfrak{M}\otimes\mathfrak{N}:\psi(E)=(\mu\otimes\nu)(E)\}$ is a monotone class containing all elementary sets in $\mathfrak{M}\otimes\mathfrak{N}$. How can I prove that $\mathcal C$ is closed under countable intersection?

Answer (score 0):

If $E_1$ has finite measure
$$\psi (\cap_n E_n) = \lim_n \psi( E_n) = \lim_n \mu \times \nu (E_n) = \mu\times\nu (\cap_n E_n).$$
For the infinite case
$$\cap_n E_n = \bigcup_r \bigcap_n E_n\cap B_r(0).$$